# Fragment XXX {} not associated with a fragment manager

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I started using navigation component in my application and I am facing with the following problem. 
My first fragment is LoginFragment. After a success login, the mainFragment is displayed. I want that when user is on mainFragment and press back button to not go back to loginFragment. For this I added these 2 lines in nav_graph : `app:popUpTo="@+id/lovable_app_navigation"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` and it works well. Here is my navigation graph :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/app_navigation"
  app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.xxx.LoginFragment"
    android:label="LoginFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment">
    <action
      android:id="@+id/dashboard_action"
      app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
      app:launchSingleTop="true"
      app:popUpTo="@+id/app_navigation"
      app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
  </fragment>

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.xxx.MainFragment"
    android:label="MainFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment">
       <action
      android:id="@+id/logout_action"
      app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
      app:launchSingleTop="true"
      app:popUpTo="@+id/app_navigation"
      app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
  </fragment>

  <action
    android:id="@+id/action_global_loginFragment"
    app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
</navigation>
```

The problem is that after a time, when my session expires, it doesn't matter where the user is in application, in which fragment, I must to display the LoginFragment over the all stack. I created a global action for this `action_global_loginFragment`. The problem is that when I navigate to LoginFragment I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment LoginFragment{1d6bd24 (829a6832-3480-4bcb-a3f6-7e2ba214d3ca)} not associated with a fragment manager.
```

If I remove `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` it works fine, but then the back button functionality is affected, from mainFragment it goes back to loginFragment. 
Any idea how to fixed this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24):

The same issue was happening to me, I managed to solve it by wrapping the `navigate` method inside a `view?.post` call like so:

```
view?.post {
    findNavController().navigate(SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToLoginFragment())
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Basically, you are checking if fragment still attached to do so. If not, is because you have navigated already. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Amg91 This solution works but why do we have control in an already Garbage Collected/backPressed fragment?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is caused when you try to call `findNavController()` on a fragment that has been detached, if you're using Kotlin you can create an extension function like so

```
fun Fragment.findNavControllerSafely(): NavController? {
    return if (isAdded) {
        findNavController()
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

then use it in any fragment

```
findNavControllerSafely()?.navigate(/*pass here the nav directions>*/)
```

you can also surround it with try/catch but I do not recommend this as it will silently catch/ignore other exceptions that might be useful, try navigating through the source code of `findNavController()` to get a better feel of the kind of exceptions that are thrown

Comment: "I do not recommend this as it will silently catch/ignore other exceptions that might be useful"

Or you may just catch the exception you are interested on...

Comment: @FranMarzoa Yes you're right, totally missed that :D

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too and its very confusing to know whats wrong!

I found this URL That helped me a lot!:[Android Navigation Component Issue](https://dev.to/sh3lan93/android-navigation-component-issue-ik3)

This guy suggest to create a function on every fragment, due to **when using the findNavController() with a fragment that isn't NavHostFragment or isn't within NavHostFragment this exception will be thrown.**

```
fun Fragment.getFragmentNavController(@IdRes id: Int) = activity?.let {
    return@let Navigation.findNavController(it, id)
}
```

Then, you can all your navigation instance with the id just like this:

```
getFragmentNavController(R.id.shipping_host_nav).navigate(R.id.id_of_host_nav)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue today.
the problem was with the importing of the wrong file.
there are actually 3 files that can be imported.

1. import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController

   *This says findNavController()*
2. import androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController

   *This says findNavController(Activity, Int)*
3. import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController

   *This says findNavController(Fragment)*

If I used 2nd one it gave an error Fragment not attached/associated with/to an Activity. (don't remember the exact error)

If I used 3rd one I was getting the same error as @Gabrielle

so, for me, the first one worked perfectly fine since it doesn't require either Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

im cereate an extention for this issue , it work based on fragments lifecycle and kotlin

```
fun NavController.lifeCycleNavigate(lifecycle :LifecycleCoroutineScope, resId :Int) =
    lifecycle.launchWhenResumed {
        navigate(resId)
    }
```

now we can use it simply with navController , like this

```
findNavController().lifeCycleNavigate(lifecycleScope  , R.id.destination )
```

Answer (score -1):

for me the problem was the fragment after restoration because of config change was the fragment manager was not valid in fragment so I had to get it directly from activities like this:

```
activity?.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)?.navigate(....)
```

or

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.setFragmentResultListener(.....)
```